# XML XPath question

Tags: xml, xpath

```
 <categories>
<member>
    <name> Ants </name>
    <size> 8 </size>
    <submember>
        <structure>
            <name>Acrobat Ants </name>
            <size>Slightly over 1/8" </size>
            <color>Tan, red with heart shaped abdomen </color>
            <habitat>Inside moist wood</habitat>
            <found>Throughout the US</found>
            <desc></desc>
            <productLink> </productLink>
        </structure>

        <structure>
            <name>Argentine Ant </name>
            <size>About 1/16" </size>
            <color>Light to dark brown </color>
            <habitat>Shallow areas with moist soil</habitat>
            <origin>Argentina and Brazil</origin>
            <desc></desc>
            <productLink></productLink>
        </structure>    

        <structure>
            <name>Carpenter Ants </name>
            <size>1/4-1/2" </size>
            <color>Varies</color>
            <Habitat>Inside decayed or moist wood</Habitat>
            <Found>Throughout the US</Found>
            <desc>C</desc>
            <productLink></productLink>
        </structure>
     </submember>
 </member>
 </categories>
```

Let's say I have a XML file like this (the actual xml is much longer than this) then how do I get "Ants" structure using xpath?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two XPath expressions that select the wanted nodes. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want the `member` which contains `Ants` as the `Name`.  This should be enough:

```
/categories/member[name=' Ants ']
```

Note the quotes include the spaces needed for the name.  Whitespace is important in XML so the spaces around `Ants` are part of the content as well.  Otherwise you could normalize the spaces first which effectively trims the excessive whitespace first before comparing.

```
/categories/member[normalize-space(name)='Ants']
```

---

As Alejandro points out, you might want the `structure` descendants under the `Ants` element.  Then you'd need to dig a bit further.

```
/categories/member[normalize-space(name)='Ants']/submember/structure
```

Comment: M: This selects `member` elements, not `structure` elements

Comment: @Alejandro: And that's what I assumed he wanted.  It wasn't very clear to me what elements he wanted.  But now that you pointed that out, I guess he would want the `structure` elements.  I originally read it as, "I want the thing that has the 'Ants' name, I don't know what to call it, but it's like a structure."  I didn't realize that there were elements that were named `structure`, I was only concerned about the 'Ants' name.  :)

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I have a XML file like this
>   (the actual xml is much longer than
>   this) then how do I get "Ants"
>   structure using xpath?

I guess that you want to select any `structure` with child `name`, whose string value contains the string "Ants".

**Use**:

```
  /*/*/*/structure[contains(name, 'Ants')]
```

This selects any `structure` element that has a child `name` that contains the string "Ants" and that (the `sructure` element) is a child of any element that is a child of any element that is a child of the top element of the XML document.

**Or, use**:

```
  /*/*/*/structure[contains(concat(name,' '), ' Ants ')]
```

This selects a `structure` element that satidfy all requirements as in the previous expression with the exception that its `name` child must contain an "Ants" preceded by a space and either followed by a space or being the ending substring of the complete string value of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few extensions to @Jeff's (good) answer. This targets all `<structure>` elements below the `<member>` whose name contains `Ants` (accounting for leading/trailing spaces):

```
/categories/member[normalize-space(name)='Ants']/submember/structure
```

Or just the first one:

```
/categories/member[normalize-space(name)='Ants']/submember/structure[1]
```

Just `Carpenter Ants`:

```
/categories/member[normalize-space(name)='Ants']/submember/structure[normalize-space(name)='Carpenter Ants']
```

And so on...

You should try to generalize these for your own uses.